# Show that $\max \left(\frac{|X_1|}{\sqrt{n}}, \dots, \frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \overset{d}{\to} 0, n \to \infty$

Tags: probability

> $X_1, X_2, \dots, X_n, \dots$ is a sequence of *i.i.d* random variables with $E[X_1] = 0$ and $E[X_1^2] = 1$. Show that 
>   $$
> \max \left(\frac{|X_1|}{\sqrt{n}}, \dots, \frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\right) \overset{d}{\to} 0, n \to \infty
> $$

I attempted to use the continuity theorem. Putting $Y_n = \max \left(\frac{|X_1|}{\sqrt{n}}, \dots, \frac{|X_n|}{\sqrt{n}}\right) $, we can show that the distribution function of $Y_n$ is 
$$
F_{Y_n}(y) = [F(\sqrt{n}y)]^n,
$$
where $F(\cdot)$ is the distribution function of $X_1$. Then the characteristic function of $Y_n$ is 
$$
\varphi_{Y_n}(t) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} n^{\frac 32} [F(\sqrt{n}y)]^n e^{ity}\,\mathrm{d}F(y)
$$
I can only get to this step and don't know how to proceed the proof. Is there an alternative way to prove it? Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to show that $P(Y_n\leqslant y)\to1$ for every $y\gt0$ (since convergence in probability implies convergence in distribution).

For every $y\gt0$, $P(Y_n\leqslant y)=(1-P(|X_1|^2\gt ny^2))^n$.

If $nx_n\to0$ then $(1-x_n)^n\to1$, hence it suffices to show that, if $Z$ is nonnegative and integrable then $nP(Z\gt n)\to0$ (and to apply this to $Z=|X_1|^2/y^2$).

Any idea for this last step? Note that $nP(Z\gt n)=E(Z_n)$ where $Z_n=$ $____$ hence $____$...

Answer (score 2):

I think we can do this with just Chebyshev's inequality: As you pointed out, we have the exact formula $P(Y_n<\epsilon)=(1-P(X_1^2\ge n\epsilon^2))^n$. Now for fixed $\epsilon>0$, we have that
$$
n\epsilon^2 P(X_1^2\ge n\epsilon^2) \le \int_{[n\epsilon^2,\infty)} x^2\, dF(x) \to 0
$$
as $n\to\infty$ by dominated convergence. Thus $P(X_1^2\ge n\epsilon^2)\le \delta/n$ eventually for arbitrary $\delta>0$ and hence
$$
P(Y_n<\epsilon)\ge (1-\delta/n)^n \to e^{-\delta} .
$$